# A RenderFlex overflowed by .. pixcels on the bottm in CarouselSlider

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I want to create a CarouselSlider function where a textbox is positioned under an image. (See photo) However, when changing its child from Stack to Column, an error like 'A RenderFlex overflowed by .. pixcels on the bottom' occurs. As a result of a Google search to fix this, I tried to use Expanded to wrap Column or Container with Expanded, but the result was the same. How do I solve it? Please help me. My code is below.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cFkF5.jpg)

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:carousel_slider/carousel_slider.dart';

List<String> imgList = [
  'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1520342868574-5fa3804e551c?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=6ff92caffcdd63681a35134a6770ed3b&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1951&q=80',
  'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1522205408450-add114ad53fe?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=368f45b0888aeb0b7b08e3a1084d3ede&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1950&q=80',
  'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1519125323398-675f0ddb6308?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=94a1e718d89ca60a6337a6008341ca50&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1950&q=80',
  'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1523205771623-e0faa4d2813d?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=89719a0d55dd05e2deae4120227e6efc&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1953&q=80',
  'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1508704019882-f9cf40e475b4?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=8c6e5e3aba713b17aa1fe71ab4f0ae5b&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1352&q=80',
  'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1519985176271-adb1088fa94c?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=a0c8d632e977f94e5d312d9893258f59&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1355&q=80'
];

class RecommendShip extends StatelessWidget {
  const RecommendShip({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final List<Widget> imageSliders = imgList
        .map(
          (item) => SizedBox(
            child: Container(
              margin: EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
              child: ClipRRect(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10.0)),
                child: Column(
                  children: [
                    Image.network(
                      item,
                      fit: BoxFit.cover,
                      width: 1000.0,
                    ),
                    Positioned(
                      bottom: 0.0,
                      left: 0.0,
                      right: 0.0,
                      child: Container(
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          gradient: LinearGradient(
                            colors: [
                              Color.fromARGB(200, 0, 0, 0),
                              Color.fromARGB(0, 0, 0, 0)
                            ],
                            begin: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                            end: Alignment.topCenter,
                          ),
                        ),
                        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                            vertical: 10.0, horizontal: 20.0),
                        child: Text(
                          'No. ${imgList.indexOf(item)} image',
                          style: TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.white,
                            fontSize: 20.0,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                              ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        )
        .toList();

    return CarouselSlider(
      options: CarouselOptions(
        autoPlay: false,
        enlargeCenterPage: true,
      ),
      items: imageSliders,
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap your `Image` with `Flexible` with `flex: 1`.
So your code should look like this:

```
Flexible(
   flex: 1,
   child: [Your Image widget]
),
```

I suggest you to use Widget inspector in cases like this, it can be really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your image with expanded widget.

```
class RecommendShip extends StatelessWidget {
  const RecommendShip({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final List<Widget> imageSliders = imgList
        .map(
          (item) => ClipRRect(
            borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10.0)),
            child: Column(
              children: [
                Expanded(
                  child: Image.network(
                    item,
                    fit: BoxFit.cover,
                    width: 1000.0,
                  ),
                ),
                Container(
                  decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                    gradient: LinearGradient(
                      colors: [
                        Color.fromARGB(200, 0, 0, 0),
                        Color.fromARGB(0, 0, 0, 0)
                      ],
                      begin: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                      end: Alignment.topCenter,
                    ),
                  ),
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                      vertical: 10.0, horizontal: 20.0),
                  child: Text(
                    'No. ${imgList.indexOf(item)} image',
                    style: const TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.white,
                      fontSize: 20.0,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
    )
        .toList();

    return CarouselSlider(
      options: CarouselOptions(
        autoPlay: false,
        enlargeCenterPage: true,
      ),
      items: imageSliders,
    );
  }
}
```